# Issue using preact with React 18 based component

Tags: reactjs, preact

I have a react 18 based component imported to the project as dependency in package.json that has a createRoot import like

`import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';`

later on this code is called as

`createRoot(el).render(selector);`

This component is later used inside the preact based app

webpack config has aliases

```
alias: {
    react: 'preact/compat',
    'react-dom': 'preact/compat'
},
```

The problem is that after bundling with webpack, createRoot is an empty function and it fails

Any solutions how to fix that?

I've tried to alias "react-dom/client" as "preact/compat" but it does not help

```
alias: {
    react: 'preact/compat',
    'react-dom': 'preact/compat',
    'react-dom/client': 'preact/compat',
},
```

webpack config

```
{
  "entry": {
    "player": "player"
  },
  "output": {
    "filename": "bundle.js",
    "path": "somepath",
    "libraryTarget": "amd",
    "publicPath": "/edit/player/"
  },
  "devtool": "inline-source-map",
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "test": {},
        "use": [
          "source-map-loader"
        ],
        "enforce": "pre"
      },
      {
        "test": {},
        "exclude": "/node_modules/",
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "babel-loader",
            "options": {
              "presets": [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                "@babel/preset-react"
              ],
              "plugins": [
                [
                  "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
                  {
                    "throwIfNamespace": true,
                    "runtime": "automatic",
                    "importSource": "preact"
                  }
                ],
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": {},
        "use": {
          "loader": "raw-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        "test": {},
        "use": {
          "loader": "url-loader?limit=100000"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "externals": [
    null,
    "runtime-react",
    "runtime-react-dom"
  ],
  "resolve": {
    "alias": {
      "react": "preact/compat",
      "react-dom": "preact/compat"
    }
  },
  "mode": "development",
  "watch": true,
  "watchOptions": {
    "ignored": {}
  },
  "optimization": {
    "minimize": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove your `react-dom/client` alias, it's incorrect and wouldn't work. What version of Preact are you using? You need to be using at least v10.8.0, though it otherwise should work. If it's not, you may have an issue in your Webpack config as, given a quick test, it seems to be working correctly in a minimal reproduction.

Comment: preact 10.11.0  Thank you, will dbl check my webpack config

Comment: updated question with my webpack config (some paths and names are modified)

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If so, how?